# Get current user Flask-User

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have step up a basic web app with the [Flask-User 1.0](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/%22Flask-User%22) connected it to my Mongodb. And the registration and login work. But once the logged in user enters the member_page I want to be able to send and receive information between the client and server. Planning on using socket.io since I have used it before. But I have now way of knowing how to get the information about the current user. I will make like a calendar for the logged in user. That the user can add and edit his own calendar. But currently I cant find out the current user and therefore not know whos information to send back to the user, same goes if the user adds something in his calendar.

If I print the session I get a bunch of information. But I have no ide how to extract the username of the current user.

```
<SecureCookieSession {'_fresh': True, '_id': 'ea37d60dd399bf244b53b5fc2b00629d11e3f0b844cbaaaa8902ad00b920133e1b4ea777d2af9492d4feffc81f9500d7e5889bd04a804c75e91e939b97fcfd22', '_permanent': True, 'csrf_token': 'e5040f2814ebf30f563635bbff459158fdd36bef', 'user_id': 'gAAAAABblr9Y80DfmIY66WOcUe5rYE6EjGgAHd5gMeH9Cst91VYKEvtYq14vAPqdgU5lzkb5ELJZrzWWg9mE2oN4_U3PsZeiHWW5iV7VWVh952WKlYEKn3SnMA0aEnOW0zSl47qqKqwB'}>
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, session
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_user import login_required, UserManager, UserMixin


# Class-based application configuration
class ConfigClass(object):
    """ Flask application config """

    # Flask settings
    SECRET_KEY = 'This is an INSECURE secret!! DO NOT use this in production!!'

    # Flask-MongoEngine settings
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        'db': 'tst_app',
        'host': 'mongodb://localhost:33420/website'
    }

    # Flask-User settings
    USER_APP_NAME = "Flask-User MongoDB App"  # Shown in and email templates and page footers
    USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = False  # Disable email authentication
    USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = True  # Enable username authentication
    USER_REQUIRE_RETYPE_PASSWORD = False  # Simplify register form


def create_app():
    """ Flask application factory """

    # Setup Flask and load app.config
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(__name__ + '.ConfigClass')

    # Setup Flask-MongoEngine
    db = MongoEngine(app)

    # Define the User document.
    # NB: Make sure to add flask_user UserMixin !!!
    class User(db.Document, UserMixin):

        active = db.BooleanField(default=True)

        # User authentication information
        username = db.StringField(default='')

        password = db.StringField()

        # User information
        first_name = db.StringField(default='')
        last_name = db.StringField(default='')

        # Relationships
        roles = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=[])

    # Setup Flask-User and specify the User data-model

    user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)

    # The Home page is accessible to anyone
    @app.route('/')
    def home_page():
        # String-based templates
        return render_template_string("""
            {% extends "flask_user_layout.html" %}
            {% block content %}
                <h2>Home page</h2>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.register') }}>Register</a></p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.login') }}>Sign in</a></p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('home_page') }}>Home page</a> (accessible to anyone)</p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('member_page') }}>Member page</a> (login required)</p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.logout') }}>Sign out</a></p>
            {% endblock %}
            """)

    # The Members page is only accessible to authenticated users via the @login_required decorator
    @app.route('/members')
    @login_required  # User must be authenticated
    def member_page():

        # String-based templates

        return render_template_string("""
            {% extends "flask_user_layout.html" %}
            {% block content %}
                <h2>Members page</h2>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.register') }}>Register</a></p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.login') }}>Sign in</a></p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('home_page') }}>Home page</a> (accessible to anyone)</p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('member_page') }}>Member page</a> (login required)</p>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('user.logout') }}>Sign out</a></p>
            {% endblock %}
            """)

    return app


# Start development web server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Solution for anyone in the future

I added this code in user_mixin.py:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_user_id_by_token(cls, token, expiration_in_seconds=None):
    # This function works in tandem with UserMixin.get_id()
    # Token signatures and timestamps are verified.
    # user_id and password_ends_with are decrypted.

    # Verifies a token and decrypts a User ID and parts of a User password hash
    user_manager = current_app.user_manager
    data_items = user_manager.verify_token(token, expiration_in_seconds)

    # Verify password_ends_with
    token_is_valid = False
    if data_items:

        # Load user by User ID
        user_id = data_items[0]
        password_ends_with = data_items[1]
        user = user_manager.db_manager.get_user_by_id(user_id)
        user_password = '' if user_manager.USER_ENABLE_AUTH0 else user.password[-8:]

        # Make sure that last 8 characters of user password matches
        token_is_valid = user and user_password==password_ends_with

    return user_id if token_is_valid else None
```

I can now call my function and user_id will be returned

```
user_id = UserMixin.get_user_id_by_token(session['user_id'])
```

Comment: You probably want [`current_user`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/a558a42f746e5f697a277fa697c688d00fe806b5/app/views/main_views.py#L39); also see [`from flask_user import current_user`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/a558a42f746e5f697a277fa697c688d00fe806b5/app/views/main_views.py#L8)

Answer (score -3):

```py
from flask_login import current_user
```

You can use this to do so, current_user is an API from Flask. Apart from that I really believe if you're a beginner you may like to follow this [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) by Miguel Grinberg